# Locally-run tests pass, but Jenkins tests fail; why, and how can I fix this?

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm running a fairly large suite of python-based tests with a much larger number of steps on an Ubuntu Linux VM. When I run them via any number of methods manually (via the console) they all run and pass just fine.

After I ported them to a Jenkins server, four out of the thirty fail. I tried the usually recommended fix - increasing the wait time for keywords to work to `1s` before every single click - so I'm fairly certain it isn't a timing issue. The site loads a lot faster than that on Windows, which I know is slower than Jenkins on Linux.

After Googling around a little for an answer, I found that apparently no one has come up with an accepted answer, either on this site or other Q/A sites.

Here's the error messages I'm getting from Jenkins.

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.79
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799289ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.10.0-33-generic x86_64)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.79
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799289ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.10.0-33-generic x86_64)
```

The other two are both `element not visible` exceptions identical to the first, both of which happen on a `Click Button` keyword that is not the first Click Button keyword in the test suite. The first one happens on a `Click Element` keyword that has worked perfectly since I wrote it, and the last one happens on tried-and-true JavaScript call to get the text of an element.

Why would something work locally on two different operating systems and then fail on Jenkins?

Comment: Few quick checks/suggestions : 1. Check Browser version on local and jenkins box where you test cases are running same or not?  2. Did you tried remote debugging attaching your local IDE to browser instance of jenkins box, if not you can try the same as well. 3. Are these 4test cases are same every time ?

Comment: Quick answers: 1) Yes. 2) Technically my IDE is a Shell script, not a full-blown IDE that I downloaded. 3) Yes.

Comment: Is the page loads on complete screen or you need to scroll the page and perform a click operation on remote machine?

Comment: The page loads in the background on a remote VM.

Comment: I meant for UI whether UI loads completely on entire page or you have to scroll in order to find and click element on UI.
 Also did you tried "wait until page load' or "wait until element is displayed" in selenium for respective element to be loaded or visible before performing any operation?

Comment: Oh, I gotcha. The UI loads completely, and the page is loaded. I know, because none of the four elements are the first to be clicked in the chain of actions.

Comment: I happened to notice something in the exception that's bothering me - the `chromedriver` on the jenkins instance is very old, most probably hardly compatible with Chrome 61 - the newest is 2.33. This might not be the culprit, but upgrading it is worth the shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why would something work locally on two different operating systems and then fail on Jenkins?

- The most common might be that the jenkins system is running slower, and your tests aren't being hyper-vigilant about waiting for pages to finish loading before trying to interact with it. Jenkins boxes often can be under a heavy load, and if both the client and server are running on the same box, either or both could be contributing to the problem.
- Another reason could be that you're running different versions of the browsers and/or selenium drivers on the jenkins box.
- Another reason could be that the resolution of the (virtual?) displays is different, causing elements to be shifted to a different position.
- The browsers on the jenkins box could have different profiles, resulting in a different set of plugins or antivirus software running. These can contribute to the speed at which a page renders, or could cause unwanted popups that cover portions of the screen.

Comment: you may run as different user on Jenkins and on nodes - master node has the same account as Jenkins service,other nodes use ones defined in node configuration,tests run via SSH (manual run) may have different users. Different users,different profiles and access rights etc.

Comment: No longer working on the system to which this question applied originally, so while there can never be a true "accepted" answer that solved the problem (short of someone else having the same problem and confirming that one of these is the cause), this is the only answer that has appeared in two years.